# capistrano 3 perimission issues on bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rvm-capistrano, capistrano3

i am getting this error suddenly while deploying rails 4 with capistrano 3. i deployed before there was no problem with nokogiri. it started appearing suddenly

```
 Errno::EACCES: Permission denied -
    /home/deploy/xxxxx/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/.autotest
    An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot
    DEBUG [b3c81f53]    continue.
    DEBUG [b3c81f53]    Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Probably bug in the version. Could you update `nokogiri` gem?

Comment: i directly ssh to the server and installed nokogiri but when again i deploy through capistrano it gives this error.

Comment: did you use the same user when logging in via ssh than you are using for deployment?

Comment: its different. but deploy user is in sudo group. it worked fine for few deployments. yes i had permission problem installing gems through deploy user(although it is in sudo group). is there anything i have to do for deploy user so that i can install gems through it